# serialize/deserialize JSON in mono touch/droid

Tags: json, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin.android

Is there a cross platform way to serialize/deserialize JSON in mono touch/droid, without using a 3rd party library like Newtonsoft.Json?

Do I have to have an object per platform?

Answer (score 1):

Both MonoTouch and Mono for Android ships with a [`System.Json.dll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) assembly which provides the same feature set you can find in Silverlight (and .NET 4.5).

Note: both MT and M4A profiles were based on Silverlight and enhanced over time to cover more API.

Comment: Trouble is when i use that on a 7KB json string i get a:
`Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.TimeOutException: Timed out.`

exception.
I have verified the json in multiple tools

Comment: Maybe you should add that to your question and maybe describe how you are deserializing/serializing.

Comment: That's a debugger (MonoDevelop) exception - it should not affect your application from running. Try to make a test case and fill a bug report (for MonoDevelop) at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com